# Partial integration of $\sin x\log(y-1)$ w.r.t. $x$

Tags: integration, logarithms

If I have the function $\sin x\log(y-1)$ and I want to partially integrate it w.r.t. $x$ then what happens to $\log $? Would the solution be: $-\cos x \log(y-1)$ and how? Isn't $\log(y-1)$ a function or a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are concerned with the function $(x,y) \mapsto \sin x \log |y-1|$.

Let $y \neq 1$ and let $f: x \mapsto \sin x \log |y-1|$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$
\int_{x} \sin x \log |y-1| = -\log|y-1|\int_{x} D\cos x = -\cos x \log|y-1| + \text{some constant}.
$$

But if you are concerned with the function $x \mapsto (x, f(x)) =: (x,y) \mapsto \sin x \log |y-1|$, then of course you cannot simply treat $y$ as a constant...

Comment: I am trying to understand why the complete line $(\log(y-1))$ is taken as constant instead of just `y`?

Comment: You may see that by checking the definition of partial derivative or simply treat it as a univariate function.

Comment: Also, it depends on how you define a function.